# Changing suspend order on OpenSUSE 12.2

Tags: opensuse, suspend, gdb

This question seems more relevant here than SO. I've been trying to debug a library that X uses through a GDB session that I'm running through SSH, but it seems that on OpenSUSE, the SSH session is being "suspended" before GDB hits a breakpoint that occurs in the library on suspend. As a result, the system waits on the remote GDB to continue, but I can't continue because the SSH session is "suspended".

I noticed on Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10, the GDB session stops while the SSH connection is still active, so I can continue on the breakpoint and continue on the SIGUSR1 signal that GDB gets. Is it possible to mimic this behaviour on SUSE and "reverse" the order of suspends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the difference between the two distros. I removed /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50rcnetwork, and now the SSH session suspends after GDB gets the SIGUSR1 signal.